# a python function that returns the value of a dictionary

Tags: python

How could I write a function that, given the dictionary and key names, returns that value or False, example:

```
d = {'a1' : 1, 'a2' : 2, 'a3' : {'b1' : 3, 'b2' : 4, 'b3' : {'c1' : 5}}}
get_dval(d, 'a1') => 1
get_dval(d, 'a3', 'b1') => 3
get_dval(d, 'a3', 'b3', 'c1') => 5
get_dval(d, 'a1', 'b2') => False
```

Comment: Kindly consider googling for answers before posting on SO.

Comment: I have not found a site that discusses this problem.  thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is the `get` method. I.e.:

```
>>> my_dict = {'a': 2}
>>> my_dict.get('a', False)
2
>>> my_dict.get('b', False)
False
```

In the case that you need this as one function you could do:

```
def get_dval(dict_, first_idx, *args):
    if not isinstance(dict_, dict):
        return False
    if len(args) == 0:
        return dict_.get(first_idx, False)
    else:
        if first_idx not in dict_:
            return False
        return get_dval(dict_[first_idx], *args)
```

Or you could do something like:

```
def get_dval(dict_, *args):
    try:
        for idx in args:
            dict_ = dict_[idx]
    except:
        return False

    return dict_
```

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for, as there would be as many function calls as there are dimensions in the dictionary.  ex: d.get('a3').get('b1') and d.get('a3').get('b3').get('c1')

Comment: Thanks!  that looks a lot closer, I ran the quick test of get_dval(d, 'a3', 'b3', 'c1') and it returned False, but should have returned 5.  Will try and edit that function.

Comment: You don't seem to use any keys but the last in `get_dval`.

Comment: the later `dict_` should be `dict_.get(args[0])`, and your code would raise exception on edge cases.

Comment: This works for all the cases except the one that doesn't exist, like get_dval(d, 'a1', 'b2'), is there an easy way to return False if any of the keys don't exist?

Comment: Well, technically what you mean is for the cases where a key exists, but it's not a dictionary. Anyway, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Non-recursive function:

```
def get_dval(value, *args):
    args = list(args)
    while args:
        try:
            value = value.get(args.pop(0), False)
        except Exception:
            # deal with non-dict `dict_` which not hasattr `__getitem__`
            value = False
            break
    return value
```